# 2 different system settings menus on different machines

Tags: menu, system-settings

I have 2 18.04 systems both fully updated but they have different system settings menus?

why are they different?

thanks

[system settings 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5TWQ.jpg)
[system setting 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni34H.jpg)

also the window menu options are different, and there is a window title bar across the top:

[window menu options 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8P2C.jpg)
[window menu options 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysBdT.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, what are the difference(s) ? I fail to see them.

Comment: the names are different:

colors versus device color profiles
displays versus screen displays

Comment: I don't see any difference either

Comment: In systems setting the icon name are different

and in the window options photos there are more options on the window menus, and a triple bar across the top of the window